# Firing JavaScript events more than once

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My problem is that whenever I set up an event it only ever fires once. In my current code all I want to do is set the div that the viewer clicks on to one class and set the other divs to a different class. Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = document;
function acc(id){
    var opn = d.getElementsByClass('opn')[0];
    var elem = d.getElementById(id);

    if(opn.id != id){
        opn.className = 'clo';
        elem.className = 'opn';
    }
}
</script>
```

And my HTML is:

```
<div id="a" class="opn" onclick="acc('a');">a</div>
<div id="b" class="clo" onclick="acc('b');">a</div>
<div id="c" class="clo" onclick="acc('c');">a</div>
```

I would like the code to fire again on subsequent clicks of the div elements.

Comment: your event handler is firing every time, it's just not doing what you think it does in subsequent calls...

Comment: Your code works as expected: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37wkA/1/). I have only replaced `getElementsByClass` with `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: What is it doing in subsequent calls then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an else statement to put the class to it's original state so when it's clicked again it can be set to the new class.

Comment: I think he needs to define what he actually expects the handler to do - I assume it's supposed to be some sort of radio-button effect, where only one of the links can have an `opn` class.

Comment: That's exactly it. Though it sort of ends up more like an accordion effect.

Comment: @user1503749 and what it the already `opn` element is clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears almost correct, except that (as identified by @lanzz in the comments) you have called the wrong method to get the currently `opn` element, meaning that your later tests then fail.

This would have been reporting an error in your browser's JS console, if you had looked...

In any event, I'd suggest a modest improvement, though - there's no need to pass the `id` of the current element.

Just write your handlers like this:

```
onclick="acc(this)"
```

and update your function like this:

```
function acc(elem) {
    var opn = d.getElementsByClassName('opn')[0];

    if (opn !== elem) {
        opn.className = 'clo';
        elem.className = 'opn';
    }
}
```

I also note that *in theory* there's no need to update `opn` each time the event is fired - it should be a "live" list of Nodes that's automatically updated every time the DOM is updated.